# Getting App Running info on clicking notification

Tags: android, android-intent, notifications, intentfilter, android-pendingintent

I am working on getting the flow of the Application on Push notification click.

The flow of application I want is conditional depending on when the push notification gets clicked.

So, when the user clicks on push notification I want to know if my application is already running.

If it is, then display only Activity A on top of the already running application and on back press continue working with the old app from same activity that was active before.

If the application is not running when the notification gets clicked, I want to display Activity A and onBackPress I want to start Activity B.

The approach that I have decided is to send in an extra parameter with the Intent that starts the notification, but this extra parameter is conditional.

How do I get this kind of flow in the application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the conditional extra.

Simlply launch Activity A from the Notification. Now, in Activity A add the following code:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // If this activity is the only activity in the task, that means the
    //  app wasn't running when the notification was clicked.
    if (isTaskRoot()) {
        // Start Activity B
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        // NOTE: you should call finish() here if you want Activity A to go away now
        // finish();
    } else {
        // Otherwise, just do the normal BACK stuff (ie: finish this Activity and go
        //   back to whatever the user was doing in the app)
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Comment: Neither of the activities (A or B) qualify for root task.

Comment: Have you tried this code? What happens when you start your notification and your app is not running? Please post your manifest.